# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MathPHP\LinearAlgebra\MatrixFactory" not found in

Tags: php, laravel, composer, namespace

*meu teclado é americano, então acaba ficando dificil adicionar acento nas frases, peço perdão*

Boa tarde pessoal, apesar de eu ter alguns anos de experiência com programação, o PHP é algo novo pra mim, comecei a praticar faz alguns dias e já resolvi tentar algo mais avançado, claro que vou bater cabeça com algumas coisas básicas, por isso peço paciência. Já vi que tem tópicos relacionados mas olhando o meu código o problema parece ser diferente (ao tentar buildar e rodar  o meu projeto), vou deixar um print anexado com a montagem das pastas e também deixar o código aqui para vocês verem.

O erro que está acontecendo é esse:
 `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "MathPHP\LinearAlgebra\MatrixFactory" not found in C:\Users\Asus\Documents\GitHub\mchlrn\vendor\markrogoyski\math-php\src\main.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Asus\Documents\GitHub\mchlrn\vendor\markrogoyski\math-php\src\main.php on line 6`

Por algum motivo ele não encontra a classe MatrixFactory, acredito que falte alguma configuração ou até mesmo o meu main.php está no local errado, mas enfim, o meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
use MathPHP\LinearAlgebra\MatrixFactory;
   
$matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

$a = MatrixFactory::create($matrix);
$b = MatrixFactory::create($matrix);

$a + $b = $a->add($b);
$ab = $a->multiply($b);
$a * $b = $a->hadamardProduct($b);

$c = $a->map(function ($x) {
    return $x * 2;
});
?>
```

Obviamente falta código mas queria pelo menos conseguir buildar o meu projeto, fico grato se alguém poder dar um direcionamento, enquanto isso vou dando uma olhada nas documentações oficiais e nos outros tópicos, se eu conseguir resolver atualizo aqui. Obrigado /
[Projeto + mensagem de error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0c5P.png)

Answer (score -2):

Ola, tudo bem?

Verificou se a biblioteca foi instalada corretamente?
Se sim, adicione esse trexo de codigo na segunda linha do codigo, em cima do `use`
dessa forma:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use MathPHP\LinearAlgebra\MatrixFactory;
   
$matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
//resto do codigo a baixo
```

O arquivo `vendor/autoload.php` é gerado pelo composer e é responsável por carregar automaticamente todas as classes e bibliotecas que você instalou usando o composer. Ele é gerado com base nas dependências especificadas no arquivo composer.json.

Fazendo o require desse arquivo, voce vai permitir que seu arquivo php consiga carregar as bibliotecas instaladas no projeto

Answer (score -2):

Olá! Pela mensagem de erro, parece que você está tentando usar uma classe que não foi incluída ou importada corretamente no seu código. A primeira coisa a verificar é se a biblioteca que contém a classe MatrixFactory foi corretamente instalada no seu projeto. Você pode verificar se a biblioteca está instalada corretamente verificando se ela está listada no arquivo composer.json e se o arquivo vendor/autoload.php foi gerado.

Se a biblioteca estiver instalada corretamente, o próximo passo é garantir que você está importando ou incluindo a classe corretamente no seu código. Você está fazendo isso usando a instrução use MathPHP\LinearAlgebra\MatrixFactory;, que importa a classe MatrixFactory para o seu código. Se a biblioteca não estiver instalada ou se a classe não estiver sendo importada corretamente, isso pode causar o erro que você está vendo.

Outra coisa a verificar é se o caminho para o arquivo main.php está correto. Ele deve ser o caminho completo para o arquivo main.php a partir da raiz do seu projeto. Se o caminho estiver incorreto, isso também pode causar o erro que você está vendo.

Espero que isso ajude! Se você ainda estiver tendo problemas, pode ser útil incluir mais informações sobre o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento (sistema operacional, versão do PHP, etc.) e também fornecer mais detalhes sobre como você instalou a biblioteca e incluiu o arquivo main.php no seu projeto.